# Equals operator not available on member type that has a reference in its constructor

Tags: c++

I have a `Rectangle` class that has a member variable of type `PrintManager`.  `PrintManager` takes an ostream reference in its constructor.

```
class PrintManager
{
public:
    PrintManager();
    PrintManager(ostream&);
    ~PrintManager();

private:
    ostream& stream;
};

PrintManager::PrintManager(ostream& fileStream) : stream(fileStream){}
```

Rectangle.h

```
class Rectangle 
{
public:
    Rectangle();
    ~Rectangle();
    Rectangle(int, int);
    Rectangle(int, int, PrintManager);

private:
    PrintManager manager;
};
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int length, int width) :length(length), width(width)
{
    //error here
    manager = PrintManager(cout);
}
Rectangle::Rectangle(int length, int width, PrintManager manager) : length(length), width(width), manager(manager)
{
    //no error here
}
```

I understand that references can't be rebound, but I don't understand why I can't have the `Rectangle` constructor that doesn't pass the PrintManager in its constructor.  I'm not reassigning anything to the stream parameter, just initializing it with `cout`

Comment: @MattMcNabb is it not the case that you have to pass streams by reference?

Comment: Declare PrintManager as a pointer.

Comment: In this code `PrintManager` is non-assignable because it contains a reference.  Maybe this is OK, but it means that `Rectangle` is also non-assignable because it has a `PrintManager` member.  If you want `Rectangle` to have normal value semantics then you'd have to make a change here (either point to a PrintManager, or have the PrintManager point to a stream).

Comment: @wootscootinboogie not exactly.. you can't copy them by value, but that doesn't happen when passing by pointer

Comment: The name of the operator is **assignment operator**. Calling it *equals operator* may cause confusion with equality comparison operator (`==`). Can you change the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using assignment operator to copy a PrintManager object, which is not allowed because it has a reference member, you should do this instead:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int length, int width)
:length(length), width(width), manager(PrintManager(out))
{
}
```

which will call the copy constructor of PrintManager.

Answer (score 3):

Because you store the `PrintManager` project *as a value*, so when when the `Rectangle` constructor is called, the compiler tries to construct the `PrintManager` object as well, and it will fail since it contains a reference that needs to be initialized.

The solution is deceptively simple: Initialize the `PrintManager` object in the `Rectangle` initialize list:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int length, int width)
    :manager(std::cout), length(length), width(width)
{ }
```

Comment: I was decently certain your answer was the solution, but I didn't know the mechanics behind why.  It makes more sense now that any member variables that contain references in their construction need to be in the initialization list as well.